# No compile time errors for TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am failing to get compile time errors or successful builds for TypeScript in VS 2012. I am using this in my project file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc --module amd -target ES5         &quot; @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
</Target>
```

eg errors should look like this:

> Greeter.ts(7,26): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

any ideas?

Comment: What shows up in the Output window? Anything?

Comment: 1>  '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc --module amd -target ES5  "' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Did you recently update your TypeScript install? You may need to update the project file to point to the correct tsc.exe location (e.g. in 0.8.1.1 instead of 0.8.0.0)

Comment: nope its all there at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closing `&quot;` is misplaced. Should be:

`Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc&quot;  module amd -target ES5          @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" />`

Comment: hi, I now get this at the top of the game.js file :   define(["require", "exports", "GameObjects"], function(require, exports, __GameObjects__) {            and this error:       Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function